# limit parameter returns empty result on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

On this node + Mongodb project, I am trying to limit the number of objects I get back from the database.
The first query is to get all the objects with the 'featured' property set to 'true' which works fine, but the moment I include a limit parameter to the featured objects, it only returns an empty array.
Here is the reference code:

```
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { min, max, ...others } = req.query;
  try {
    const hotels = await Hotel.find(req.query).limit(req.query.limit);
    res.status(200).json(hotels);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Here is my request:

localhost:4000/api/hotels?featured=true&limit=3

But the limit parameter makes it return an empty array.

If I remove the limit parameter from the request, I get all the featured items, but when the limit parameter is added to the query, it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The query params returns the string value and limit take interger/number that's why you are getting empty array
Now you have two solution

1. Type cast the query value to the integer shown below

   ```
   const hotels = await Hotel.find(req.query).limit(parseInt(req.query.limit));
   res.status(200).json(hotels);
   ```
2. Multiply the query value with your inital value that will change the string to integer (let me take 1)

   ```
   const hotels = await Hotel.find(req.query).limit(1 * req.query.limit);
   res.status(200).json(hotels);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the way the query parameters are being passed and processed. In the provided code, the **'limit'** parameter is being passed as a string in the query string, and it needs to be converted to an integer for the **'Hotel.find'** query.

```
const { featured, limit } = req.query;
const parsedLimit = parseInt(limit);
const hotels = await Hotel.find({ featured: featured === 'true' }).limit(parsedLimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate limit query param and use it for limit function.

```
const { min, max, limit, ...others } = req.query;
const hotels = await Hotel.find(req.query).limit(limit);
```